# How to open current working directory (OS X/Linux/Win)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to open the current working directory in python?

```
current_wkd = os.getcwd()
print(current_wkd) 
.../User/Bob/folder
```

Say at the end of my program, I want to open the current working directory. I know how to open specific files, but I am interested in the "/User/Bob/folder" opening once the program is complete. How to open "folder" at the end of the script?

What is the best way to do this in OSX/Linux/Win.

Thank you.

For example,

In the terminal one can use:

```
pwd  # get current wkd
../User/Bob/folder  
cd /User/Bob/folder  # change directory to /User/Bob/folder
open folder # To open the directory named "folder"
```

Is this possible as part of the python script. At the end, for the directory to open as in the above "open folder" command in the terminal. I know how to find the current wkd and change it using:

```
os.getcwd()
os.chdir()
```

How do you open the current directory? In other words, at the end of my script I want the directory/folder to open. Similarly to when opening a web browser using:

```
webbrowser.open_new()
```

Thank you e9T (below) for the guidance!

ANSWER: I ended up using this as part of my script at the end:

```
import subprocess 

current_directory = os.getcwd()

subprocess.check_call(['open', '--', current_directory]) # This is for OS X
```

Comment: What do you mean by opening a folder? listing files contained in it?

Comment: Do you want to open your file-manager to that folder?

Comment: if you do `ls` inside the folder (after doing cd <folder>) you will get the list of files inside that folder and not the what is listed.

Be more specific: is opening here what the ls comand is doing?
Or do you mean a command to open the folder in a GUI app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `subprocess` to open up a file explorer for a given path.

```
import subprocess
import sys

def open_folder(path):
    if sys.platform == 'darwin':
        subprocess.check_call(['open', '--', path])
    elif sys.platform == 'linux2':
        subprocess.check_call(['gnome-open', '--', path])
    elif sys.platform == 'win32':
        subprocess.check_call(['explorer', path])

open_folder(path=".")  # open current directory
```