# How to open a folder in file explorer using python?

Tags: python, directory, cross-platform

I need to open a specific folder 'D:\folder\mainfolder' or current working directory. How can i do it using python and if possible how to do the same in linux?

Comment: You are probably looking for [os.listdir()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir)

Comment: Does this answer your question? Except instead of working directory you'd just use the specific one in your question. [How to open current working directory (OS X/Linux/Win)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28734442/how-to-open-current-working-directory-os-x-linux-win)

Answer (score 1):

You can open windows file explorer via command line and provide it a path to open. For example

```
import os

os.system(r'start D:\folder\mainfolder')
```

For linux it's a little more complicated. There is a command you can run but some distributions dont support it or deprecated it. So you'll have to double check what command your distribution supports.

```
import os

os.system(r'xdg-open D:\folder\mainfolder')
```